# How to know the interface from which we received a ping request

Tags: networking, network-interface, ping, tcpdump, ifconfig

I know how to ping to a specific interface using the `-I` option. I want to know  the interface through which I received the ping. I tried to use `tcpdump` for this but I cannot get any details. I can filter out the ping ICMP echo requests via

`tcpdump 'icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echo'`

I have 2 ethernet interfaces on my custom HW with a custom built linux. I want to check if I have configured the interfaces and routing table correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the question on it's side a bit, and use `tcpdump` to listen for packets only on a given network interface.  With that, you can limit the trace to the interface of interested when you do the test

```
# tcpdump -i <interface> ...
```

Also note that your filter -- `'icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echo'` -- will work only for ping over IPv4, so if you're dealing with IPv6 you'll need to tweak the filter accordingly.

Comment: I recognized I can do this after I asked the question :). I anyways simplified the question since I actually have 8 `eth` interfaces. I could use for a better way than listening on all and figuring out. Thank you for pointing it out though.

Comment: Ah, yeah.  With many interfaces, this is not such a good alternative :)

Comment: My `tcpdump` says you can use `-i any` to listen non-promiscuously on all interfaces. If you add `-e` you can see the remote mac address and look this up with `arp`.